# Inaccessible files and File.list()

Tags: java, file

while searching my file system for a file, my program threw a null pointer exception because File.list() could not access 'Documents And Settings' on my file system and an attempt to parse String[] myArray = File.list() when myArray was null threw the exception.

how can I check to see if a file or folder can not be access using File and keep that from happening?

Comment: Are you using a restricted (non-admin) user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`file.isDirectory()` will tell you if the `File` object represents a directory.

The documentation of `listFiles()` mentions that it will return `null` in case the `File` does not represent a directory. Additionally, you would need to check with `file.canRead()` whether the application can read the directory.

But the `File` API is really bad here, because it can return `null` if there is an I/O problem. So where you would normally catch an `IOException`, here you should check for `null`. Apache commons-io `FileUtils` for example uses exactly this approach:

```
File[] found = directory.listFiles(filter);
if (found != null) {...}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the reading really succeeds. So you're doing three system calls instead of one and get nothing in return.

Comment: @maaartinus indeed. I fixed my answer. +1 to your comment & answer.

Comment: Well I tried to open "Documents And Settings" through the OS as an Admin and even the Os blew me off and told me to get lost as I do not have permission.  Windows sucks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Just don't do it. IMHO, the only sane way is something like

```
String[] files = file.list();
if (files!=null) {
    for (String f : files) processFile(f);
}
```

It works always and avoids additional system calls. Any other approach takes more time and may fail when e.g. the permissions change in between. For `file!=null` the expression `file.listFiles()` is guaranteed to never fail.

Comment: Agreed but I thought perhaps there was a way to do this as Java can gather all files on the file system hidden, protected, whatever.  I figured since it can gather all files on the file system then it should be able to manipulate permissions.

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact Windows permissions and/or magic used for `Documents And Settings`, but I'd guess, Java can't do more than your permissions allow. The `hidden` files are only meant to be hidden from BFU, not from programs, so obviously Java can read them. I strongly doubt it can access e.g. other users' files when protected using an [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `canRead()` method to see if a folder can be read.