# Android Clear Data programmatically

Tags: java, android, file

Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19831167/2956344

i try to clear data from another package. but when i try to clear data i have a null pointer exception in line :

```
...
  if (appDir.exists() && appDir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {           // NPE! children is null
                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                    Toast.makeText(this, "App Data Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
...
```

file-explorer tool show me that the folder contains files. 
and I confusion about this. Anybody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: hi, you know the directory path isnt it?

Comment: There has to be something wrong with the reading permissions.. please take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130002/inaccessible-files-and-file-list

Comment: @Perroloco yeap i can't read this directory. Any way to fix this?

Comment: You have this in your manifest?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @Perroloco this permission need to access to files which located in external storage. But app data located in internal storage. However i add this permission and nothing will changed(

Answer (score 0):

The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.Is there any I/O error happening?